# Update posted transaction using SageDataObject220

Tags: vb.net, sage-line-50

I am trying to update  a field inside a posted transaction.

This is what I have:

```
    Dim oWS As SageDataObject220.WorkSpace
    Dim SD As SageDataObject220.SplitData = oWS.CreateObject("SPLITDATA")
    SD.Open(SageDataObject220.OpenMode.sdoWrite)

    SD.FindFirst("TRAN_NUMBER", CInt("575031"))
    SD.Read(SD.RecordNumber())
    SD.Fields.Item("Details").Value = "575031 test"
    SD.Write(SD.RecordNumber())
    oWS.Disconnect()
```

I can locate the transaction, but trying to update the Details value does not work. It appears to be read only and only comparable.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to close the SplitData object first after reading the transaction number.